# New to go; how to use math/big

Tags: go

I am new to Go but not to programming. I am trying to implement a few functions on prime numbers as a way to learn. Here's my code, which you can run at http://ideone.com/qxLQ0D:

```
// prime numbers

package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// list of primes less than n:
// sieve of eratosthenes
func primes(n int) (ps []int) {
    sieve := make([]bool, n)
    for i := 2; i < n; i++ {
        if !(sieve[i]) {
            ps = append(ps, i)
            for  j := i * i; j < n; j += i {
                sieve[j] = true
            }
        }
    }
    return ps
}

// true if n is prime, else false:
// trial division via 2,3,5-wheel
func isPrime(n int) (bool) {
    wheel := [11]int{1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6}
    w := 0
    f := 2
    for f*f <= n {
        if n % f == 0 { return false }
        f += wheel[w]
        w += 1
        if w == 11 { w = 3 }
    }
    return true
}

// greatest common divisor of x and y:
// via euclid's algorithm
func gcd(x int, y int) (int) {
    for y != 0 {
        x, y = y, x % y
    }
    return x
}

// absolute value of x
func abs(x int) (int) {
    if x < 0 {
        return -1 * x
    }
    return x
}

// list of prime factors of n:
// trial division via 2,3,5-wheel
// to 1000 followed by pollard rho
func factors(n int) (fs []int) {
    wheel := [11]int{1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6}
    w := 0 // wheel pointer
    f := 2 // current trial factor
    for f*f <= n && f < 1000 {
        for n % f == 0 {
            fs = append(fs, f)
            n /= f
        }
        f += wheel[w]; w += 1
        if w == 11 { w = 3 }
    }
    if n == 1 { return fs }
    h := 1 // hare
    t := 1 // turtle
    g := 1 // greatest common divisor
    c := 1 // random number parameter
    for !(isPrime(n)) {
        for g == 1 {
            h = (h*h+c) % n // the hare runs
            h = (h*h+c) % n // twice as fast
            t = (t*t+c) % n // as the tortoise
            g = gcd(abs(t-h), n)
        }
        if isPrime(g) {
            for n % g == 0 {
                fs = append(fs, g)
                n /= g
            }
        }
        h, t, g, c = 1, 1, 1, c+1
    }
    fs = append(fs, n)
    return fs
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(primes(100))
    fmt.Println(isPrime(997))
    fmt.Println(isPrime(13290059))
    fmt.Println(factors(13290059))
}
```

That works fine. I would like to know how to initialize `wheel` as a constant at compile time so that it can be shared by `isPrime` and `factors`, and I would appreciate any comments on style or other aspects of my program.

I eventually want to implement some factoring algorithms on big integers, using the `math/big` package. But I'm having much trouble. Simplifying to just the trial division via a 2,3,5-wheel part of the algorithm, here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func factors(n big.Int) (fs []big.Int) {
    zero := big.NewInt(0);
    one  := big.NewInt(1);
    two  := big.NewInt(2);
    four := big.NewInt(4);
    six  := big.NewInt(6);
    wheel := [11]big.Int{*one,*two,*two,*four,*two,*four,*two,*four,*six,*two,*six}
    w := 0;
    f := two;
    for big.Mul(*f, *f).Cmp(n) <= 0 {
        for big.Mod(n, *f).Cmp(*zero) {
            fs = append(fs, *f)
            n = big.Div(n, *f)
        }
        f = big.Add(f, wheel[w])
        w += 1
        if w > 11 { w = 3 }
    }
    fs = append(fs, n)
    return fs
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(factors(*big.NewInt(13290059)))
}
```

That doesn't work; ideone complains that the `Add`, `Div`, `Mod` and `Mul` functions are not found. And it looks rather ugly to me, stylistically.

Please tell me how to fix my `factors` function.

**EDIT 1:** Thanks to @TClaverie, I now have a function that compiles. Now I am getting a runtime error, and ideone points to the `Mul` function. Once again, can anyone help? My revised code is shown below and at http://ideone.com/aVBgJg:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func factors(n *big.Int) (fs []big.Int) {
    var z *big.Int
    zero := big.NewInt(0)
    one  := big.NewInt(1)
    two  := big.NewInt(2)
    four := big.NewInt(4)
    six  := big.NewInt(6)
    wheel := [11]*big.Int{one,two,two,four,two,four,two,four,six,two,six}
    w := 0
    f := two
    z.Mul(f, f)
    for z.Cmp(n) <= 0 {
        z.Mod(n, f)
        for z.Cmp(zero) == 0 {
            fs = append(fs, *f)
            n.Div(n, f)
            z.Mod(n, f)
        }
        f.Add(f, wheel[w])
        w += 1
        if w > 11 { w = 3 }
        z.Mul(f, f)
    }
    fs = append(fs, *n)
    return fs
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(factors(big.NewInt(13290059)))
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Thanks to @TClaverie, I've learned a lot about Go, and I'm close to a solution. But I still have one problem; the program

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    one   := big.NewInt(1);
    two   := big.NewInt(2);
    four  := big.NewInt(4);
    six   := big.NewInt(6);
    wheel := [11]*big.Int{one,two,two,four,two,four,two,four,six,two,six}
    f := two; w := 0
    for f.Cmp(big.NewInt(40)) < 0 {
        fmt.Println(f, w, wheel)
        f.Add(f, wheel[w])
        w += 1; if w == 11 { w = 3 }
    }
}
```

prints the following output, which shows that `wheel` is being modified in the call to `Add`:

```
2 0 [1 2 2 4 2 4 2 4 6 2 6]
3 1 [1 3 3 4 3 4 3 4 6 3 6]
6 2 [1 6 6 4 6 4 6 4 6 6 6]
12 3 [1 12 12 4 12 4 12 4 6 12 6]
16 4 [1 16 16 4 16 4 16 4 6 16 6]
32 5 [1 32 32 4 32 4 32 4 6 32 6]
36 6 [1 36 36 4 36 4 36 4 6 36 6]
```

What's the right way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: You are changing the value of `two`, which is held by `f`. Change it to `f := big.NewInt(2)`

Comment: Got it. Working now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you look at the documentation, you'll see that `Add`, `Div` and `Mul` are defined for the type `*big.Int`, so you have to call them using a `*big.Int` with the dot notation. Also, they expect arguments of type `*big.Int`, but you're giving them `big.Int`.

If you look at the documentation, you'll also see that those functions are of the type: `z.Op(x, y)`. They apply `x Op y` and store the result into another `*big.Int` called `z`. So, you need a dummy `*big.Int`, that I'll call `z` (the methods return it at the same time).

Finally, it's better to work with pointers in this case, as all methods work with pointers.

```
func factors(n big.Int) (fs []big.Int) --> func factors(n *big.Int) (fs []big.Int)
wheel := [11]big.Int{*one,*two,*two,*four,*two,*four,*two,*four,*six,*two,*six} -->
wheel := [11]*big.Int{one,two,two,four,two,four,two,four,six,two,six}

big.Mul(*f, *f) --> z.Mul(f, f)
big.Mod(n, *f) --> z.Mod(n, f)
n = big.Div(n, *f) --> n.Div(n, f)
f = big.Add(f, wheel[w]) -−> f.Add(f, wheel[w])
```

A last thing: your condition is broken in the second for, because you are giving it an `int` instead of a `boolean`.

So, I do not guarantee the code works after those modifications, but you will be able to make it compile and debug it.

Comment: Thank you. I made several changes, as shown in the EDIT to my original question, but there is still something wrong, a runtime error on the `Mul` function. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You have a nil z, so it panics on the first occurrrence. Init it with a dummy value.